# My Backbone.View won't render

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I reorganized my fully-working Backbone.js project and moved all my models, collections and views into separate files, and did a little rewriting, and now it won't render. I've tried everything I can think of. Any tips?

```
var SessionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: Session,
    el: '#list',
    template:  _.template($('#session-template').html()),
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this));
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template({sessions: sessionList}));
        return this;
    }
});
var sessionView = new SessionView();

var SessionListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#list',
    model: sessionList,
    initialize: function () {
        sessionList.bind('add', this.add, this);
        sessionList.bind('reset', this.add, this);
        sessionList.fetch();
    },
    render: function () {
        var view = new sessionListView();
        this.$el.append(view.render().el);
        new SessionView({model: Session});
        return this;
    }
});

var sessionListView = new SessionListView();
```

Comment: surely it's `this.model.on`, not `this.model.bind`? (But it's even better to use [listenTo](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo))

Comment: @i .on is a newer version of bind, is all. That's not the issue. I just printed out sessionList (which is a collection containing 4 objects) from SessionListView, but it seems to be empty. Could it be that the objects are lost somewhere on the way is responsible for the empty list on my page? I should also clarify that SessionView and SessionListView are located in separate files.

Answer (score 1):

Few things that I noticed:

1. [`Backbone.View`](http://backbonejs.org/#View) does not have a model property. Only [`Backbone.Collection`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) has a model property, which backbone will use to create an instance of model using the specified model **constructor** (*blueprint*) and data passed to it.

   But  views doesn't have a functionality like this (*as far as I know*). People usually pass an **instance** of a specific type of model with the options while creating a view, that's not the same as specifying a model property which points to a model constructor in the View's constructor.

   `sessionList` doesn't seems to be an instance of a model (*since it is specified in the view's constructor. If it's an instance it'll be shared by all the `SessionListView` instances which is not the desired behavior in most cases*) and seems to  be `undefined`

   in the following:`new SessionView({model: Session});` `Session` doesn't look like an instance of a model (*Doesn't start with a capital letter, hoping you're following naming conventions*) and also seems to  be `undefined`

   Well nothing is stopping you from specifying a model constructor in view's constructor or passing a model constructor into the view, but then you should make an instance of it (*mostly while initializing*) inside the view to work with. In other words you can not do `blueprintOfAModel.bind('change'..);` and you should build an actual model for the view to work with.
2. You seems to be creating new `SessionListView` in the `render` method of `SessionListView` itself with `var view = new sessionListView();` won't that create infinite number of `SessionListView` instances when you simply try to create one..?

   Well by looking at it again, you are not calling the actual constructor `SessionListView` with the `new` operator, but with an instance of it (`sessionListView`) which is likely to throw an error.
3. Both `SessionView` and `SessionListView` points to the same element, which seems weird. I haven't seen people doing that before since modifying the `el` of one view will have an impact on the other view, which is not desired in most practical cases.

   Also judging by the names, since you have a *list* view of *session*, `SessionView` should not be pointing to a particular element with an `id` selector. You should create a new element for each SessionView instance. Backbone will do that for you if you don't specify `el` property.

(*I'd say you created an unintentional mess that wasn't there with a little rewrite :*)

---

To make sense, your code should *look somewhat* like the following. Note that things starting with capital letter are constructor *functions* and things starting with small letters are *object* instances

```
var Session = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {},
  initialize: function() {}
});
var SessionList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Session,
  initialize: function() {}
});
var SessionView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this));
    this.render();
  },
  template: _.template($('#session-template').html()),
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({
      session: this.model
    }));
    return this;
  }
});
var SessionListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#list',
  initialize: function() {
    this.collection.bind('add', this.add, this); // method doesn't exist, should throw error
    this.collection.bind('reset', this.add, this); // same here
    this.collection.fetch();  // <--- watch out, this happens asynchronously
  },
  render: function() {
    // iterate through collection, create instances of SessionView and append to el
    return this;
  }
});

var sessionList = new SessionList(); // will create n number of Session instances in future

var sessionListView = new SessionListView({ // will create n number of SessionView instances in future
  collection: sessionList
});
```

Comment: @T Thanks, I believe I have made a mess and now I'm all confused :P What would you recommend I put in which View? Should the template be loaded in the item view (ie SessionView)? I'm trying to render data from a Collection (sessionList) in a table. What should go in the SessionListView?

Comment: @almosthacker read the updated answer again and check the code, might help to understand the concept. If you don't then you should probably read more tutorials and stuff before trying to rewrite working stuff :)